# Login user - keep session

Tags: android

What is the best way to implement a login user session?  So, when I log in, I want to be able to open user details and see information there ... Is it best to save the password and encrypted password in shared preferences (call api for user details with username and password), or save the data  about the user in the model - sqllite (Room), is there any better way?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please, be more specific on protocols and authentication schema you use.

Comment: i'd use a database to store the user's connected. then do a query to see if user is connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend to store password. There are different approaches for handling login sessions. You have to care about different things to keep it secure. For instance, sessions revocations and permissions.

I would recommend to look into some standards like [JWT](https://jwt.io/). With JWT you can store some claims and user data right inside the token. The way you store the token itself is up to you, just take care that it is accessible for your application only.

Answer (score 0):

String password is never advised. You can use below-mentioned approache to save details:

1. Generate a unique session ID for each user at the time of login and send it as a response from the server to the app. Save this session ID (unique ID) in your DB/Shared Preference.
2. Whenever you want to get the user details, query the server again, sending the unique ID along with the request. Validate the session ID (unique ID) at the server for a valid request, and in turn, return the details based on the passed ID
3. Render the output based on the received response.

If you want user details to be instantly available, without hitting an API, you can rather save the details directly into the DB and load it as and when required.

Instead of saving password and/or using shared preference, DB will be a better option to store data. And by this approach, you are eliminating the need to save password and can get the user details as and when required too.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have a login:**
Never save the password as a clear text. You can do it this way:

1. Create a "password salt" (save it in the database corresponding to the user)

---

```
public static String CreateSalt() {
    Random random = new SecureRandom();
    byte[] salt = new byte[16];
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    return new String(salt);
}
```

2. Get password from the users input, add the salt and do a one way algorithm like MD5 
   *text = password + salt*

---

```
public static String HashMD5(String text){
    try {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        // digest() return array of byte
        byte[] messageDigest = md.digest(text.getBytes());

        // Convert byte array into signum representation
        BigInteger no = new BigInteger(1, messageDigest);

        // Convert message digest into hex value
        String hashtext = no.toString(16);
        while (hashtext.length() < 32) {
            hashtext = "0" + hashtext;
        }
        return hashtext;
    }
    // For specifying wrong message digest algorithms
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

3. Now you can save the hashed passoword in the database
4. The next time the users loggs in you can get the passwordsalt from the database (by the username), add it to the password the users wants to logg in and hash it. Now you can compare it with the hashed password in the database

**This is best way to do it because of the privacity laws. This way you wont have any idea of any password from your users so you can grant the seccurity of your app !**

In case you **have NOT a loggin** but want to keep your apps identified in any way you can do it like this:

1. Create a UUID and save it in the shared preferences

---

```
private static String UUID_KEY = "UUID";
public static <T> boolean Save(String key, T value, Context context){
    init(context);
    if(value instanceof String){
        editor.putString(key, (String) value);
    }else if(value instanceof Double){
        editor.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits((Double)value));
    }
    else if(value instanceof Integer){
        editor.putInt(key, (Integer) value);
    }
    else if(value instanceof Boolean){
        editor.putBoolean(key, (Boolean) value);
    }
    return editor.commit();
    //TODO add more types --> This should be a generic method in the future

}

 public static boolean NewUUID(Context context){
    String UUID = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    return Save(UUID_KEY,UUID, context);
}
```

2. Get the UUID on every start

---

```
public static <T> T Get(String key, Class _class, Context context){
    init(context);
    if(_class == Double.class){
        return (T)(new Double(Double.longBitsToDouble(sp.getLong(key, Double.doubleToLongBits(_defaultValueDouble)))));
    }
    else if(_class == Integer.class){
        return (T)(new Integer(sp.getInt(key,defaultInteger)));
    }else if(_class == String.class){
        return (T)(new String(sp.getString(key,defaultValue_string)));
    }else if(_class == Boolean.class){
        return (T)(new Boolean(sp.getBoolean(key,defaultBoolean)));
    }
    return null;
}
 public static String GetUUID(Context context){
    return Get(UUID_KEY, String.class, context);
}
```

---

**You can save the UUID in your database and relate some information to it. This way you skip the loggin part of your application!**